# Physical assumptions directions orthogonal to the direction of a Lorentz boost

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

On p. 26 of D' Inverno's GR book, he argues that suppose we have two observers $A$ and $A'$ with parallel axes $y,z$, and that $A'$ moves along the $+x$ direction of $A$ with speed $v$. Then $y'= ny$, and similarly for $z$. However, the author doesn't specify the functional dependence of $n$ to $v$ or to $x,y,z$. It is reasonable to suppose that $n(v)$, i.e. independent of position. The author argues that $n = +1$ since $y = y'$ when $v = 0$.

I'm not sure this follows logically from the fact that $y = y'$ whenever $v = 0$, since it might be the case that the sign of $n$ flips as $v$ increases. However as a physical assumption it seems reasonable that at the outset we should set $n(v) > 1$. My question is whether this is a reasonable assumption... or if possible how do we justify this assumption more rigorously.